# Deployed Maven Attached Artifacts on Github Remain Inaccessible

Tags: maven, deployment, apache-karaf, github-package-registry

I have a maven module which is configured with a *feature* packaging (an Apache Karaf feature). This project has no primary artifact to deploy but an attached feature.xml file. When I try to deploy the project to Github package the upload seems to work:

```
Uploaded to github: https://maven.pkg.github.com/cdelg-ct/repo/com/mycompany/app/my-mod/1.0-SNAPSHOT/my-mod-1.0-20200701.090836-1-features.xml
```

But then, the above file does not show up in the Github Packages UI and other projects cannot depend on it (Could not find artifact). Note the pom is well deployed as the other sibling jar modules.

Did anyone manage to get classifier to work with Github Maven Packages?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a SNAPSHOT version.
By default, SNAPSHOT versions are not fetched.
Quick way to check it, try a release version.
If it works, you have to configure your maven settings to allow spapshots versions.

Comment: Yes, Maven is configured to use SNAPSHOT versions. The exact same settings works well when deployed into a local folder or a remote Artifactory instance. Looks like a Github issue.

Comment: Could you install maven feature and run maven:repository-list -v. If snapshot is set to true, you are mostly right about a github issue.